# Diffusion through wire cloth using Darcy's law

Tags: thermodynamics, diffusion

I am currently working on a heat pipe project and I am stuck at this point where I need to calculate if methanol can diffuse through 15 complete turns of a stainless steel wire mesh( seen in pic). 
I know for a fact that I have to use Darcy's law to calculate it, but I have no idea how to use it (shame really), mostly because I can't seem to find the values for the parameters involved, but this part is crucial to me because I need to find out if using 15 turns in my heat pipe is feasible.

Here's the dimensions of the mesh. 
Wire Dia= 0.035 mm , Wire Width =0.07mm and porosity comes down to 63%.

So if anybody can help me out with this ,it would be great ,and please mention if I need to give anymore details about the dimensions of the heat pipe.

[image: This is how the mesh looks]

Comment: What has Darcy's law for flow through porous media got to do with diffusion?

Comment: @Chester Doesn't the equation give flow rate through the porous medium? I wanted to know if methanol could diffuse through the 15 turns of wire mesh.

Comment: Yes, but that's not called diffusion.  Maybe you mean effusion or percolation?  In any event, I'm sure there is information available on the permeability of a stack of screens (of specified wire diameters and opening) over the internet.  Have you Googled something like Permeability of Screen Arrays or Stacks?

Comment: I found some stuff under Permeability of Wire Mesh Filters

Comment: I am sorry for the late response, got caught up with the project work. It's not really effusion or percolation. Ok, to give you an idea, these pipes are mounted vertically, and the liquid/vapor in it has to flow up and down these pipes, one of these phases flow within the inner side of the mesh while the other flows on the outer side. At one point, their pressure and temperature drops and converts into the other's phase and has to 'diffuse' through the mesh to get to the other side. And I can't really find a better word to explain that.

Comment: We have the porosity and permeability value with us, we have formula to calculate them. Apparently, this 'diffusion' is a whole different thing that affects the working in a different way , and that's where this Darcy's equation came in. But thank you for the information, will look into that as well